# Hypnotix on Ubuntu 23.04

Tags: 23.04

Im trying to install the IPTV program Hypnotix on Ubuntu 23.04. But i have not succeeded. I have googled around a bit and im starting to think the problem is that Ubuntu 23.04 is very new and for some reason doesnt support Hypnotix yet?
Does anyone know what the problem might be?
Best regards
Ubuntu newcomer
Emil

Comment: You have it reversed. The question should be "When will Hypnotix support Ubuntu 23.04?". Please [edit] (<- click here) your question and give us details about "not succeeded". Please read  https://askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask and https://askubuntu.com/help/formatting

Comment: You are having this problem because the Hypnotix developers are using neither the standard Debian Project tools and archives nor Snaps for easy distribution. Take up the issue with the Hypnotix community -- it's their decision. Several good alternatives are available in the Ubuntu Software application, and those will install easily.

Answer (score 0):

Using `mint-tools` PPA:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:kelebek333/mint-tools
sudo apt install hypnotix
```